# Como desligar a inicialização do menu ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, menu

Gostaria de saber como eu desligo a inicialização do menu do **Ionic** em determinada página, já que não quero que os `services` do mesmo sejam ativados também.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta algo do tipo:

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
   disableBack: false,
   historyRoot: true
 });

$ionicHistory.clearCache();
$ionicHistory.clearHistory();

$state.go("nhaac.perfil");
```

Declarando o $ionicHistory no seu controller.

Comment: Não sei bem se é isso, porque sua pergunta foi meio genérica. Se detalhar melhor posso dar uma resposta mais pontual.

Comment: Exemplo, eu tenho uma página de login, quero que quando o aplicativo começar a primeira página a rodar seja ela e o controller/service dela... mas esta acontecendo o oposto, o primeiro a ser executado é o Menu... ai não carrega certas coisas

Comment: Para desativar a barra da página inicial em sua view, em <ion-view> adicione hide-nav-bar="true"

Comment: Desativar a view eu sei, só não sei desativar o controller/service inicial.